# Administrative processing for B2 US Visa for 6 months, is this time normal?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, dual-nationality, french-citizens, lebanese-citizens

I am dual citizen of France and Lebanon and have been using an ESTA to visit the USA for the past years. (2-3 trips to the US per year to visit kids studying there).

When I tried to renew my ESTA on April 19, I got "travel not authorized" and was advised to apply for a regular B2 visa. I had an appointment on April 30th at the US embassy in Paris, and the only question that the Consular officer asked me was: "you also have a Lebanese passport right?" then he handed me DS5535 to fill in. Which I did the same day.

Since then (6 months) I have been in "administrative processing" with no update on my case. I sent several emails to the embassy and their answer has always been "you have to wait".

Is this normal? What can I do?